# Wie zählbar ist „Training“?

Tags: grammatical-number

Verschiedene Wörterbücher geben den Plural von *Training* als [*Trainings*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Training) an, und ich lese das auch häufig. Ich benutze den Plural nicht und würde beispielsweise *Trainingseinheiten* (oder bei klarem Kontext nur *Einheiten*) sagen. Kommt meine Abneigung daher, dass der Plural tatsächlich vor 10 oder 20 Jahren noch weniger gebräuchlich war, oder bin ich nur vom Englischen beeinflusst, wo *training* ein [*mass noun*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/training) ist?

Oder ist vielleicht nur die Bedeutung von *Training* als *Trainingseinheit* neuer und die Wörterbücher meinen den Plural in anderen Zusammenhängen?

Beispiele *(Achtung, Links führen zu einer werbeverseuchten Website)*:

- [Das Auslaufen, auch als Cool-down bezeichnet, dient der Nachbereitung von intensiven Lauftrainings.](http://www.runnersworld.de/training/auslaufen.261045.htm)
- [3,5 versus 4 Trainings/Woche](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25140/wie-z%C3%A4hlbar-ist-training)

Comment: Für mich ist es auch ein _singulare tantum_, mir fällt kein Zusammenhang ein, in dem ich von mehreren Trainings sprechen würde.

Comment: @chirlu, ich wäre natürlich auch damit zufrieden, das weiterhin einfach als falsch anzusehen.

Comment: @Chirlu: Und wenn Du verschiedene Trainings miteindander vergleichst?

Comment: @user unknown: Würde ich wohl nicht machen, sondern verschiedene Trainingsmethoden, -verfahren, -schemata, -pläne.

Comment: Du weichst aus! Dass sich die Trainings in Methode, Schema oder was immer unterscheiden kann ja eine Erkenntnis sein, die erst kommt, nachdem der Vergleich der unterschiedlichen Trainings begonnen wurde.

Comment: Ich denke, dass "Trainings" im Plural häufig gebraucht wird, auch im sportlichen Kontext. Es mag sein, dass es in der Vergangenheit nicht der Fall war, aber wie wir uns erinnern: Sprache ist ein lebendiges Konzept.

Comment: @SteffenRoller, und daher frage ich.

Answer (score 2):

Beide Optionen treffen zu: *Training* hat die Bedeutung "Trainingseinheit", aber auch "Seminar" oder "Fortbildung", und es wird in beiden Bedeutungen auch im Plural gebraucht. Seit wann das so ist, kann ich nicht sagen, aber ich denke, der Duden dokumentiert hier letztlich, wie so oft, den tatsächlichen Sprachgebrauch. Beispiele findest Du z.B., wenn Du bei Linguee nach ["Trainings durchführen"](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/trainings+durchf%C3%BChren.html) oder ["drei Trainings"](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=drei+trainings) suchst:

> Sie werden an drei Trainings teilnehmen, in denen Sie wichtige Grundlagen für Ihre spätere Tätigkeit lernen.
>   Führen Sie pro Tag drei oder vier Trainings von jeweils 10 - 15 Minuten durch.
>   Auch in diesem Jahr bietet KOFF vier Trainings zu ausgewählten Themen der zivilen Friedensförderung an.
>   Saisonvorbereitung hinsichtlich der Laktatkapazität für einen
>   Kraftausdauersport mit drei aktiven Trainings pro Woche
>   Wir bereiten auch auf die
>   Bewerbungsgespräche vor, indem wir Trainings durchführen und auswerten.
>   Diese Prozesse unterstützen wir, indem wir ganzheitliche Projekte konzipieren und
>   konkrete Workshops und Trainings durchführen.
>   Ihr Trainer informiert Sie gern über unsere
>   zahlreichen weiteren Trainings, die wir ausschließlich firmenintern durchführen.

Du hast aber auch nicht unrecht mit Deiner Annahme, dass *Training* nicht zählbar sei. Der Begriff kann auch, ähnlich wie Bildung, für eine unbestimmte Menge von Übungseinheiten verwendet werden. Der [Wikipedia-Artikel zu Training](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training) beschäftigt sich hauptsächlich mit dieser Bedeutung und ordnet den Gebrauch des Wortes im Sinne von "Trainingseinheit" der Umgangssprache zu:

> Umgangssprachlich spricht man bereits bei einer einmalig durchgeführten Übungseinheit von Training. Im wissenschaftlichen Diskurs wird zwischen Übung und Training unterschieden.

Ein Beispiel wäre (sorry für die Klischees):

> Ohne intensives Training und einen eisernen Willen wirst Du das Ziel des Marathonlaufes nicht erreichen.

Comment: Danke. In der Bedeutung „Fortbildung“ stößt mir „Trainings“ übrigens weniger unangenehm auf, wahrscheinlich weil mir das einerseits auch neu zu sein scheint und  es mir andererseits als Business-Sprech erscheint, bei dem ich ohnehin weghöre. In der Bedeutung scheint es auch im Englischen zählbar zu sein, was, wenn ich das richtig gesehen habe, das Oxford Dictionary auch noch nicht dokumentiert hat.

Comment: Der Plural erscheint mir den Fällen auch plausibler, wo man es einfach durch *Kurs* ersetzen kann.